# How to rank criteria based on survey response?

Tags: survey, likert, scales, composite

I have made a survey to weight the importance of different features of a credit card using a 5 point Likert scale with scores (very important = 5...neither important or unimportant = 1). I have 8 criterions, each having a similar question, such as the one below:

How important is the cash back feature on a credit card?

```
Very Important
Important
Slightly important
Not very important
Neither important or unimportant
```

All 8 questions follow the same format and wording, each associating with a different credit card feature.

After conducting 10 surveys, what must I do to then determine which feature is the most important, in order to compute weights for each feature that equals to 1. Bear in mind that I am not a mathematician or a statistician. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Code the Likert scale from 0 to 4 with "Neither.." being the 2. Then count Likert scores for all 8 items. Sum the total score. Item scores divided by the total are the relative weights that range from 0 to 1 and sum up to 1.